# TensorFlow - softmax on a placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax

I've just started playing with TensorFlow. I'm unable to get `tf.nn.softmax` working with `tf.placeholder`. This piece of code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

shape = [1, 3]
value = 0.
probs = tf.constant(value, shape=shape)
sampling_prob = tf.nn.softmax(probs)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(sampling_prob))
```

as expected, returns `[[ 0.33333334  0.33333334  0.33333334]]`. But when I change it to:

```
probs2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=shape)
sampling_prob2 = tf.nn.softmax(probs2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(sampling_prob2, feed_dict={probs2: np.full(shape, value)}))
```

suddenly I get `[[ 0.  0.  0.]]`. How can it be possible?

Running on Windows 10, Python 3.5.2, TensorFlow 0.12, CUDA 8.

Comment: It's working correctly for me, Ubuntu 14.04, Python 2.7, TensorFlow 0.11 CPU only

Answer (score 0):

Code works fine for me (Ubuntu, Python 2, TensorFlow 0.11 GPU, CUDA 8). Windows support for TensorFlow is really new (within a month or so) - looks like you might want to mention this in their issues: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues.